# Is Bolg part of Azog?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, orcs

In the Hobbit Part 3 Movie, Legolas calls Bolg "the spawn of Azog." My understanding is that Azog is his father (from the wikia), but how exactly does an Orc reproduce? The term spawn is what really make me wonder because it typically means that the being was made with unconventional reproductive mean, as in not coitus. So how does an Orc like Azog produce spawn? Is Bolg technically a part of Azog?

Comment: For the record,"spawn" is occasionally used as a derogatory way to refer to children; I imagine Legolas is being intentionally insulting here

Comment: @JasonBaker from what I gather in that answer, "after the manner" so since Ilúvatar's children have coitus that means Orcs do also? Pretty gross... But a bit disappointing female orcs are not portrayed (to my knowledge) in any of the 6 Jackson films...

Comment: Being disappointed at everything left out of the Jackson films will keep you sad for a long time.

Comment: Yes, "after the manner of" is Tolkien-speak for "the same way as." I can't speak to female Orcs in the movies; there aren't any female Dwarves either (except maybe one or two extras in one of the Erebor prologue scenes)

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer "female orcs are not portrayed" ... how would you know?

Comment: @MikeEdenfield Orc boobies.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield fair enough, maybe some of those smaller ones are actually female... Ohh god, excuse me for a minute

Comment: http://thesaurus.yourdictionary.com/spawn